# How to compute loss given formula?

Tags: python, pytorch

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.03677.pdf) the method of depth estimation is proposed. There is a disparity smoothness loss
[image]

where N is number of pixels, d is the disparity map, I is the image. I wonder if the following implementation in `torch` is correct, since I am getting poor results and want to exclude possibility of incorrect implementation.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.linalg as LA

class DisparitySmoothnessLoss(nn.Module):
    
    @staticmethod
    def x_grad(image):
        image = F.pad(image, (0, 1, 0, 0), mode='replicate')
        grad_x = image[:, :, :, :-1] - image[:, :, :, 1:]
        return grad_x

    @staticmethod
    def y_grad(image):
        image = F.pad(image, (0, 0, 0, 1), mode='replicate')
        grad_y = image[:, :, :-1, :] - image[:, :, 1:, :]
        return grad_y

    
    def forward(self, disparity_map, image):
        disparity_grad_x = self.x_grad(disparity_map)
        disparity_grad_y = self.y_grad(disparity_map) 
        image_grad_x = self.x_grad(image)
        image_grad_y = self.y_grad(image)
        
        return torch.mean(torch.abs(disparity_grad_x) * torch.exp(-LA.vector_norm(image_grad_x, dim=1, keepdim=True)) + \
                torch.abs(disparity_grad_y) * torch.exp(-LA.vector_norm(image_grad_y, dim=1, keepdim=True)))
```

Comment: You might be able to compare it with the [Monodepth code](https://github.com/mrharicot/monodepth/blob/b76bee4bd12610b482163871b7ff93e931cb5331/monodepth_model.py#L109) where they implement a disparity smoothness loss of their own.

Answer (score 0):

I expect a list of grads into disparity grads like [that](https://github.com/OniroAI/MonoDepth-PyTorch/blob/0b7d60bd1dab0e8b6a7a1bab9c0eb68ebda51c5c/loss.py#L84) implementation. On [paper](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/unsupervised-monocular-depth-estimation-with) with code you can check many implementations of that article, you can also transform the TensorFlow ones (the official) to PyTorch if you do not trust into PyTorch one.